# Reading spreadsheets with Java and JXL / JExcel

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jxl

My code is opening the spreadsheet and just reading the last line ... What am I doing wrong?

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/promocoes.xls"));

//Number of lines of plannilha
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  
int linhas = sheet.getRows();

for(int i = 0; i < linhas; i++){

    Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0, i);
    Cell a2 = sheet.getCell(1, i);           

    String as1 = a1.getContents();
    String as2 = a2.getContents();

        nomepromocao = as1;
        tipopromocao = as2;         
}
workbook.close();

    driver.findElement(By.name("nomePromocao")).sendKeys(nomepromocao);
    driver.findElement(By.name("descPromocao")).sendKeys(tipopromocao);
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it is "just reading the last line"? Your code doesn't produce any output, so how could you possibly tell?

Comment: @rmlan 
Produces yes, I use the values ​​in a variable and it fills a form on my record, which I put there is the important part , the one who interacts with the worksheet .
I updated the question with the code WedBriver selenium and two variables that I use.

Comment: Ok, well based on the code you have posted, your loop re-writes the values of those variables every iteration. Naturally, the final values of these variables will be the last values encountered in the loop, and thus the last line of data in the file.

Comment: @rmlan 
And how do I change it to read the data in the order they are in the spreadsheet? I am new to programming and I could not very well apply logic.

Comment: The loop is already reading everything in the order that they are in. Try adding `System.out.println(as1 + ", " + as2);` in your loop. It may help you understand what is happening.

Comment: @rmlan
He printed the values ​​on the island, but still do not understand what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the values before the next iteration in you loop:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/promocoes.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  
int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
    String nomePromocao = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();
    String descPromocao = sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents();

    driver.findElement(By.name("nomePromocao"))
          .sendKeys(nomePromocao);

    driver.findElement(By.name("descPromocao"))
          .sendKeys(descPromocao); 
}
workbook.close();
```

You could also store the values to use them later:

```
// to store all the records
List<HashMap> records = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/promocoes.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  
int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
    HashMap<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
    record.put("nomepromocao", sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents());
    record.put("tipopromocao", sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents());
    records.add(record);      
}
workbook.close();

// to iterate each record
for(HashMap<String, String> record : records){

    driver.findElement(By.name("nomePromocao"))
          .sendKeys(record.get("nomepromocao"));

    driver.findElement(By.name("descPromocao"))
          .sendKeys(record.get("descPromocao"));

}
```